# Did Kazuki Takahashi had any involvement with the Yu-Gi-Oh Duel Monsters Anime?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, kazuki-takahashi

There still debate on whether or not Kazuki Takahashi was involved with the original Duel Monsters anime, since NAS Studio and TV Tokyo has changed some stuff that was not in his Original Manga.
And there's been no Comic Con Q&A, interviews, or any Volume notes that he ever stated he was officially involved.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Could you [edit] and mention some of the changes? The regulation for TV broadcasts may be stricter than printed media, if any of them is relevant.

Comment: Possibly related: [How did the Yu-Gi-Oh anime differ from the manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/24197/2516)